Type chooser trait
I need a type_chooser trait that would look like
using chosen_type = type_chooser<bool1, T1, bool2, T2, ....., boolN, TN, Telse>;

and would work like
if      (bool1) return T1;
else if (bool2) return T2;
...
else if (boolN) return TN;
else            return Telse;

How can this be implemented (c++20)?
It would be nice if it could accept even number of arguments as well, in which case it would work like:
if      (bool1) return T1;
else if (bool2) return T2;
...
else if (boolN) return TN;
else            COMPILE_TIME_ERROR;


You cannot mix NTTPs and type template parameters in variadic template. Can you use std::bool_constant<B> instead?

Or wrap the bool+type in a template, something like template <bool, typename> struct MTypeSelector{};.

This can only be made work if your boolean values are also known at compile time.

Mixed non-type/type parameters like that just aren't available for an arbitrary number of arguments.
You can try changing the syntax. Here are some options:
// One argument for the bool and the type
template<bool B, typename T>
struct Case;
template<typename T>
struct Else;

using chosen_type = type_chooser<Case<bool1, T1>, Case<bool2, T2>, ....., Case<boolN, TN>, Else<Telse>>;

// Maybe written as
using chosen_type = first_with_member_type<std::enable_if<bool1, T1>, std::enable_if<bool2, T2>, ..., std::enable_if<boolN, TN>, std::type_identity<TElse>>;

// Type-only arguments
using chosen_type = type_chooser<std::bool_constant<bool1>, T1, std::bool_constant<bool2>, T2, ..., std::bool_constant<boolN, TN>, Telse>;

// Or non-type-only arguments
using chosen_type = type_chooser<bool1, std::type_identity<T1>{}, bool2, std::type_identity<T2>{}, ..., boolN, std::type_identity<TN>{}, std::type_identity<TElse>{}>;

// Move all the bools to a single parameter
using chosen_type = type_chooser<std::integer_sequence<bool,
    bool1, bool2, bool3, ..., boolN
>,     T1,    T2,    T3, ...,    TN, TElse
>;

// Write out your if/else chain
using chosen_type = decltype([]{
  if constexpr      (bool1) return std::type_identity<T1>{};
  else if constexpr (bool2) return std::type_identity<T2>{};
  ...
  else if constexpr (boolN) return std::type_identity<TN>{};
  else                      return std::type_identity<Telse>{};
}())::type;

// If you have a known max number of types
template<
    bool B1 = false, typename T1 = void, bool B2 = false, typename T2 = void,
    bool B3 = false, typename T3 = void, ...,
    bool BN = false, typename TN = void, bool B(N+1) = false, typename T(N+1) = void
>
struct type_chooser;

using chosen_type = type_chooser<bool1, T1, bool2, T2, ..., boolN, TN, true, TElse>;


Proposing the old non-variadic way (up to some limit) might be useful too template<bool B1, typename T1, bool B2 = false, typename T2 = void, bool B3 = false, typename T3 = void> (doesn't handle the odd case).

Provided that:
#include <tuple>
#include <ranges>
#include <functional>

A one-liner solution for the impatient is:
template<typename tpl, bool ... cond>
requires (sizeof...(cond)==std::tuple_size<tpl>{})
using choose_type
    = std::tuple_element
    < std::ranges::size 
    ( std::array{ not cond..., false}
    | std::views::all
    | std::views::take_while
    ( std::identity{} ) ) //size
    , tpl >;
>;

It basically counts the initial false conditions to index the elements of a std::tuple. To use it:
using my_long
    = typename choose_type
    < std::tuple
    < short, long, float>
    , false, true, false>::type;

There are several problems however. You need to make sure the types provided are well-defined even if the corresponding selecting conditions are false; there's no clean solution otherwise. The other problem is incomplete types, in which case another level of indirection through std::type_identity should be introduced:
#include <type_traits>
template<typename ... Ts>
using type_list 
    = std::tuple
    < std::type_identity<Ts> //pointer to type
    ...>;

/*Blah blah*/
using choose_type
    = std::tuple_element_t // mind the '_t' dereference
/*Blah blah*/

using my_long
    = typename choose_type
    < type_list //the added indirection level
    < short, long, float>
    , false, true, false>::type;

But in case this fits the needs you can tweak it for better interface.
